# Parse Js API on Smartface

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, smartface.io

I'm a beginner to **Smartface**, and I want to use Parse in the app.
I have two questions about that:

- First one: I don't know if I can use Parse Js API because there's
  only JSON tutorials. So, can Smartface use Parse Js API?
- Second:
  Doing some research I found a folder named "Parse" in "C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Smartface\Smartface App Studio 4.4\Data\Plugins\", but in this
  folder there's another one named "Android".
   So if I use this plugin,
  will **iOS** be supported?